# When would you know a distribution up to a proportionality constant?

Tags: probability

I'm reading "An Introduction to MCMC for Machine Learning" by C. Andrieu, N. De Freitas, A. Doucet, and M. I. Jordan.

In the section providing motivation on why we'd use Markov Chain Monte Carlo analysis, the authors discuss rejection sampling, and take as a given a distribution known up to proportionality constant. That means that you can't integrate your distribution, right? For the data I'm working with, your distributions are basically histograms and you just take a sum. I understand that there are functions which aren't integrable, but is that what they're talking about? What's a concrete example where you'd actually need to relax your requirement to knowing the distribution only up to a constant multiplier?

Comment: A distribution always integrates out to 1. Nobody says that doing that integral is going to be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Many (most?) non-trivial [graphical models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model) fit this.

For example, in a Markov random field, you have that the joint density factors into products based on cliques in a graph, so, you can write the density as $p(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \frac{1}{Z}\prod_{cliques} p(clique)$ where $Z$ is the partition function (or unknown normalizing constant). You can specify the graph structure or learn it from data. But, computing the normalizing constant may be complex/non trivial without monte carlo methods, and you can do a lot without actually explicitly relying on what $Z$ is (it can disappear in various inference tasks).

There are many examples of graphical models -- Ising models (which occur in physics and machine learning), Latent Dirichlet Analysis (a graphical model which occurs in natural language processing), [computer vision](http://vision.stanford.edu/teaching/cs231b_spring1213/slides/segmentation.pdf), etc.